# Getting "The '+' operator cannot be applied to type 'symbol'." when trying to concatenate $route.name

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuejs-routing

Trying to get the current route name within a template, to pass it on to a router link (i.e. passing the current route to the login view, so I can return users there after they authenticate).

It works as expected, but when doing a type check I get:

> ```
> The '+' operator cannot be applied to type 'symbol'.  
>    :to="'/signin/' + $route.name".  
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

My code is simple enough:

```html
<RouterLink
      v-if="!userState.signedIn"
      :to="'/signin/' + $route.name"
      >Sign in</RouterLink
    >
```

Is there a way for my to annotate my code or something so that Typescript will understand that $route.name is actually a string? Or maybe get the route name differently?

Following TJ Crowder advice in comments, I can convert/cast the property to a string using:

```
:to="'/signin/' + String($route.name)"
```

... but I guess that would fail if `$router.name` comes as a `symbol`. Can't find when the value would be a `symbol` instead of a `string`.

Comment: Try `'/signin/'.concat($route.name)`.

Comment: @bassxzero - If `$route.name` is a Symbol, that doesn't work either. You can't implicitly convert Symbols to strings, hence the error.

Comment: *"Is there a way for my to annotate my code or something so that Typescript will understand that $route.name is actually a string?"* The first step is to find out why it thinks it's a Symbol.

Comment: I don't use Vue.js so apologies if I'm off in the tall grass here, but [here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#Type-Aliases-RouteRecordName) it says that the `name` of a `RouteRecordName` is of type `string | symbol`. Is that what `$toute.name` is above? If so, then the issue is that it *could be* a symbol (or a string). If you're sure it is actually a string, you can use explicit conversion to avoid the error: `:to="'/signin/' + String($route.name)"`. (But with a Vue-hat on, someone may be able to provide a better approach.)

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. Yes, you are obviously right. I'm sorry to say I am new on this js/ts/vue world and trying to wrap my head around the basics. Can't properly follow the libraries code, can't make complete sense of the docs, and it confuses me the usefulness of a property being able to hold basically incompatible types. Will try to figure out under what circumstance the `RouteRecordName` could be a `symbol` and not a `string`. Casting the property works, so I'll try that until hopefully a Vue Lord can enlighten me further. Thanks again!

Comment: @SteveMarooni - Glad that helped! FYI, `String($route.name)` is *conversion*, not casting. JavaScript doesn't have casting because it's loosely-typed, and TypeScript doesn't have casting because it's compile-time only, but casting (in languages that has it) can change the value of something at runtime. For the type-related aspects of cast, TypeScript has [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), which are similar but never have an effect on the runtime value. Anyway, have fun learning! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
:to="`/signin/${$route.name}`”
```

Try writing it this way